# Preprocessing string data in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, nltk, data-cleaning

I have a user review dataset. I have loaded this dataset and now i want to preprocess the user reviews(i.e. removing stopwords, punctuations, convert to lower case, removing salutations etc.) before fitting it to a classifier but i am getting error. Here is my code:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    df=pd.read_json("C:/Users/ABC/Downloads/Compressed/reviews_Musical_Instruments_5.json/Musical_Instruments_5.json",lines=True)
    dataset=df.filter(['overall','reviewText'],axis=1)
    def cleanText(text):
        """
        removes punctuation, stopwords and returns lowercase text in a list 
        of single words
        """
        text = (text.lower() for text in text)   

        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
        text = BeautifulSoup(text).get_text()

        from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
        tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
        text = tokenizer.tokenize(text)

        from nltk.corpus import stopwords
        clean = [word for word in text if word not in 
        stopwords.words('english')]

        return clean

    dataset['reviewText']=dataset['reviewText'].apply(cleanText)
    dataset['reviewText']
```

I am getting these errors:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-f42f70ec46e5> in <module>()
----> 1 dataset['reviewText']=dataset['reviewText'].apply(cleanText)
      2 dataset['reviewText']

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   2353             else:
   2354                 values = self.asobject
-> 2355                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   2356 
   2357         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-64-5c6792de405c> in cleanText(text)
     10     from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
     11     tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
---> 12     text = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
     13 
     14     from nltk.corpus import stopwords

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\regexp.py in tokenize(self, text)
    127         # If our regexp matches tokens, use re.findall:
    128         else:
--> 129             return self._regexp.findall(text)
    130 
    131     def span_tokenize(self, text):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

and

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-f42f70ec46e5> in <module>()
----> 1 dataset['reviewText']=dataset['reviewText'].apply(cleanText)
      2 dataset['reviewText']

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   2353             else:
   2354                 values = self.asobject
-> 2355                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   2356 
   2357         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-69-5c6792de405c> in cleanText(text)
     10     from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
     11     tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
---> 12     text = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
     13 
     14     from nltk.corpus import stopwords

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\regexp.py in tokenize(self, text)
    127         # If our regexp matches tokens, use re.findall:
    128         else:
--> 129             return self._regexp.findall(text)
    130 
    131     def span_tokenize(self, text):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Please suggest corrections in this function for my data or suggest a new function for data cleaning.

Here is my data:

```
    overall reviewText
0   5   Not much to write about here, but it does exac...
1   5   The product does exactly as it should and is q...
2   5   The primary job of this device is to block the...
3   5   Nice windscreen protects my MXL mic and preven...
4   5   This pop filter is great. It looks and perform...
5   5   So good that I bought another one. Love the h...
6   5   I have used monster cables for years, and with...
7   3   I now use this cable to run from the output of...
8   5   Perfect for my Epiphone Sheraton II. Monster ...
9   5   Monster makes the best cables and a lifetime w...
10  5   Monster makes a wide array of cables, includin...
11  4   I got it to have it if I needed it. I have fou...
12  3   If you are not use to using a large sustaining...
13  5   I love it, I used this for my Yamaha ypt-230 a...
14  5   I bought this to use in my home studio to cont...
15  2   I bought this to use with my keyboard. I wasn'...
```

Comment: `cleanText` is very poorly defined. There is so much in it that is wrong. But first, please indent your code correctly.

Comment: @Abdou I have indented my code now. As i am new to this, i am trying to find a way to preprocess my data.

Comment: Please don't do this... You're repeatedly looping through the same text multiple times in the several steps, they can be lumped into one. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47769818/why-is-my-nltk-function-slow-when-processing-the-dataframe and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48049087/applying-nltk-based-text-pre-proccessing-on-a-pandas-dataframe and https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/basic-nlp-with-nltk

Answer (score 10, accepted):

print(df)

```
    overall reviewText
0   5   Not much to write about here, but it does exac...
1   5   The product does exactly as it should and is q...
2   5   The primary job of this device is to block the...
3   5   Nice windscreen protects my MXL mic and preven...
4   5   This pop filter is great. It looks and perform...
5   5   So good that I bought another one. Love the h...
6   5   I have used monster cables for years, and with...
7   3   I now use this cable to run from the output of...
8   5   Perfect for my Epiphone Sheraton II. Monster ...
9   5   Monster makes the best cables and a lifetime w...
10  5   Monster makes a wide array of cables, includin...
11  4   I got it to have it if I needed it. I have fou...
12  3   If you are not use to using a large sustaining...
13  5   I love it, I used this for my Yamaha ypt-230 a...
14  5   I bought this to use in my home studio to cont...
15  2   I bought this to use with my keyboard. I wasn'...
```

To convert into lowercase

```
df.loc[:,"reviewText"] = df.reviewText.apply(lambda x : str.lower(x))
```

To remove punctuation and numbers

```
import re
df.loc[:,"reviewText"] = df.reviewText.apply(lambda x : " ".join(re.findall('[\w]+',x)))
```

To remove stopwords, you can either install stopwords or create your own stopword list and use it with a function

```
from stop_words import get_stop_words
stop_words = get_stop_words('en')

def remove_stopWords(s):
    '''For removing stop words
    '''
    s = ' '.join(word for word in s.split() if word not in stop_words)
    return s

df.loc[:,"reviewText"] = df.reviewText.apply(lambda x: remove_stopWords(x))
```

Comment: Thanks Sahil, your answer really helped. Can you please also suggest a function for stemming.

Comment: @ShubhamSingh look at this for stemming https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37443138/python-stemming-with-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Please don't do this... You're repeatedly looping through the same text multiple times in the several steps, they can be lumped into one. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47769818/why-is-my-nltk-function-slow-when-processing-the-dataframe and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48049087/applying-nltk-based-text-pre-proccessing-on-a-pandas-dataframe and https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/basic-nlp-with-nltk

Comment: I get AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'