# NLTK-based text processing with pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, nltk

The punctuation and numerical,lowercase  are not working while using nltk.

**My code**

```
stopwords=nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')+ list(string.punctuation)
user_defined_stop_words=['st','rd','hong','kong']                    
new_stop_words=stopwords+user_defined_stop_words

def preprocess(text):
    return [word for word in word_tokenize(text) if word.lower() not in new_stop_words and not word.isdigit()]

miss_data['Clean_addr'] = miss_data['Adj_Addr'].apply(preprocess)
```

**Sample Input**

```
23FLOOR 9 DES VOEUX RD WEST     HONG KONG
PAG CONSULTING FLAT 15 AIA CENTRAL 1 CONNAUGHT RD CENTRAL
C/O CITY LOST STUDIOS AND FLAT 4F 13-15 HILLIER ST SHEUNG HONG KONG
```

**Expected Output**

```
 floor des voeux west
 pag consulting flat aia central connaught central
 co city lost studios flat f hillier sheung
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47769818/why-is-my-nltk-function-slow-when-processing-the-dataframe

Comment: @alvas I'd be interested in comparing the performance of the stuff in your post vs mine :-)

Comment: I think yours is faster. Too lazy to benchmark things and the necessary steps heavily depends on the task and how "noisy" the data source is.

Comment: If you're interested in benchmarking more preprocessing scripts, I've another from https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/basic-nlp-with-nltk which is surely slower but the main goal to explain the steps more than fast =)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your function is *slow* and is incomplete. First, with the issues -

1. You're not lowercasing your data.
2. You're not getting rid of digits and punctuation properly.
3. You're not returning a string (you should join the list using `str.join` and return it)
4. Furthermore, a list comprehension with text processing is a prime way to introduce readability issues, not to mention possible redundancies (you may call a function multiple times, for each `if` condition it appears in.

Next, there are a couple of glaring inefficiencies with your function, especially with the stopword removal code.

1. Your `stopwords` structure is a *list*, and `in` checks on lists are *slow*. The first thing to do would be to convert that to a `set`, making the `not in` check constant time.
2. You're using `nltk.word_tokenize` which is unnecessarily slow.
3. Lastly, you shouldn't always rely on `apply`, even if you are working with NLTK where there's rarely any vectorised solution available. There are almost always other ways to do the exact same thing. Oftentimes, even a python loop is faster. But this isn't set in stone.

First, create your enhanced `stopwords` as a *set* -

```
user_defined_stop_words = ['st','rd','hong','kong'] 

i = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
j = list(string.punctuation) + user_defined_stop_words

stopwords = set(i).union(j)
```

The next fix is to get rid of the list comprehension and convert this into a multi-line function. This makes things so much easier to work with. Each line of your function should be dedicated to solving a particular task (example, getting rid of digits/punctuation, or getting rid of stopwords, or lowercasing) -

```
def preprocess(x):
    x = re.sub('[^a-z\s]', '', x.lower())                  # get rid of noise
    x = [w for w in x.split() if w not in set(stopwords)]  # remove stopwords
    return ' '.join(x)                                     # join the list
```

As an example. This would then be `apply`ied to your column -

```
df['Clean_addr'] = df['Adj_Addr'].apply(preprocess)
```

---

As an alternative, here's an approach that doesn't rely on `apply`. This should be work well for small sentences.

Load your data into a series -

```
v = miss_data['Adj_Addr']
v

0            23FLOOR 9 DES VOEUX RD WEST     HONG KONG
1    PAG CONSULTING FLAT 15 AIA CENTRAL 1 CONNAUGHT...
2    C/O CITY LOST STUDIOS AND FLAT 4F 13-15 HILLIE...
Name: Adj_Addr, dtype: object
```

Now comes the heavy lifting.

1. Lowercase with `str.lower`
2. Remove noise using `str.replace`
3. Split words into separate cells using `str.split`
4. Apply stopword removal using `pd.DataFrame.isin` + `pd.DataFrame.where`
5. Finally, join the dataframe using `agg`.

```
v = v.str.lower().str.replace('[^a-z\s]', '').str.split(expand=True)

v.where(~v.isin(stopwords) & v.notnull(), '')\
 .agg(' '.join, axis=1)\
 .str.replace('\s+', ' ')\
 .str.strip()

0                                 floor des voeux west
1    pag consulting flat aia central connaught central
2           co city lost studios flat f hillier sheung
dtype: object
```

To use this on multiple columns, place this code in a function `preprocess2` and call `apply` -

```
def preprocess2(v):
     v = v.str.lower().str.replace('[^a-z\s]', '').str.split(expand=True)

     return v.where(~v.isin(stopwords) & v.notnull(), '')\
             .agg(' '.join, axis=1)\
             .str.replace('\s+', ' ')\
             .str.strip()
```

```
c = ['Col1', 'Col2', ...] # columns to operate
df[c] = df[c].apply(preprocess2, axis=0)
```

You'll still need an `apply` call, but with a small number of columns, it shouldn't scale too badly. If you dislike `apply`, then here's a loopy variant for you -

```
for _c in c:
    df[_c] = preprocess2(df[_c])
```

---

Let's see the difference between our non-loopy version and the original -

```
s = pd.concat([s] * 100000, ignore_index=True) 

s.size
300000
```

First, a sanity check -

```
preprocess2(s).eq(s.apply(preprocess)).all()
True
```

Now come the timings.

```
%timeit preprocess2(s)   
1 loop, best of 3: 13.8 s per loop
```

```
%timeit s.apply(preprocess)
1 loop, best of 3: 9.72 s per loop
```

This is surprising, because `apply` is seldom faster than a non-loopy solution. But this makes sense in this case because we've optimised `preprocess` quite a bit, and string operations in pandas are seldom vectorised (they usually are, but the performance gain isn't as much as you'd expect).

Let's see if we can do better, bypassing the `apply`, using `np.vectorize`

```
preprocess3 = np.vectorize(preprocess)

%timeit preprocess3(s)
1 loop, best of 3: 9.65 s per loop
```

Which is identical to `apply` but happens to be a bit faster because of the reduced overhead around the "hidden" loop.

Comment: Just to clarify - converting the list comprehension to a multi-line function has nothing to do with speed, and more for code readability, right? Because from what I understand, list comprehensions - put very simplistically - are an abstraction of `for` loops in C, which are must faster than `for` loops in Python.

Comment: @alichaudry Yes, mainly readability in this case. One slight correction, python for loops and list comprehension syntax are directly implemented in C code (at least, for the Cpython implementation) and so is quite fast.

Comment: hi -@cs95 i read your answer which is quite accurate, but i have another question in same scenario, what if i have more than one Text columns in the dataframe, how can we tokenize and pad_sequences those columns and reassign them to the Dataframe again. Here is my question posted,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67769093/after-tokenize-a-column-of-text-how-to-reassigned-that-tokenized-output-which