# Passing a pandas dataframe column to an NLTK tokenizer

Tags: python, string, pandas, nltk, tokenize

I have a pandas dataframe raw_df with 2 columns, ID and sentences. I need to convert each sentence to a string.  The code below produces no errors and says datatype of rule is "object."

```
raw_df['sentences'] = raw_df.sentences.astype(str)
raw.df.sentences.dtypes
```

Out: dtype('O')

Then, I try to tokenize sentences and get a TypeError that the method is expecting a string or bytes-like object. What am I doing wrong?

```
raw_sentences=tokenizer.tokenize(raw_df)
```

Same TypeError for

```
raw_sentences = nltk.word_tokenize(raw_df)
```

Comment: What package is `tokenizer.tokenize` from?

Comment: what does the data look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming this is an NLTK tokenizer. I believe these work by taking sentences as input and returning tokenised words as output.

What you're passing is `raw_df` - a `pd.DataFrame` object, *not* a `str`. You cannot expect it to apply the function row-wise, without telling it to, yourself. There's a function called `apply` for that.

```
raw_df['tokenized_sentences'] = raw_df['sentences'].apply(tokenizer.tokenize)
```

Assuming this works without any hitches, `tokenized_sentences` will be a column of lists.

Since you're performing text processing on DataFrames, I'd recommend taking a look at another answer of mine here: [Applying NLTK-based text pre-proccessing on a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48049087/applying-nltk-based-text-pre-proccessing-on-a-pandas-dataframe/48049425#48049425)